# fractions.Fraction limit numerator?

Tags: python, fractions

[fraction.Fraction.limit_denominator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) exists, and finds the closest fraction that has a denominator smaller than a given maximum. But there is no obvious way to *limit the numerator*.

What is the best way to also limit the numerator? (I.e. to *find the closest fraction* that has both numerator and denominator smaller than a given maximum.)

(Goal: I need to limit the numerator also to 2**32, because TIFF files store fractions as two unsigned 32-bit integers.)

A crude approach (that probably does not find the truly *closest* fraction):

```
from fractions import Fraction
def limit_32bit_rational(f: float) -> Fraction:
    ndigits = 15
    while True:
            r = Fraction.from_float(f).limit_denominator(1000000)
            if r.numerator < 2**32:
                return r
            f = round(f, ndigits)
            ndigits -= 1
```

Is there a better way to find the *closest* fraction that has nominator and denominator less than 2**32?

Comment: `.limit_denominator(min(2**32, 2**32/f))` should keep both parts of the fraction in range.  (Although those should perhaps be 2**31 instead - I don't recall whether TIFF fractions are signed or not.)

Comment: @jasonharper TIFF requires unsigned integers. Could you explain how / why that works in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`float.as_integer_ratio()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/as_integer_ratio.html) method to get the numerator and denominator of any float:

```
f = 2345.245624
numerator, denominator = (f).as_integer_ratio()
print("Numerator", numerator)
```

Output:

```
2578624833578781
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can try using an `if` statement to check if the numerator or denominator is greater than `2 ** 32`; if so, multiply each of them by a scale and round them to the nearest whole numbers:

```
def limit_32bit_rational(f):
    numerator, denominator = (f).as_integer_ratio()
    max_num = 2 ** 32
    if numerator > max_num or denominator > max_num:
        scale = max_num / max(numerator, denominator)
        return round(numerator * scale), round(denominator * scale)
    return numerator, denominator
```

Comment: @Peter With the numerator you can use an `if` statement to limit it.

Comment: @Peter Then I'm afraid it's not quite clear. Can you edit your question to elaborate? Do you mean you want every number greater than 2\*\*32 to be 2\*\*32?

Answer (score 1):

You could also flip the fraction and call [`limit_denominator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) to limit the numerator and flip the result back again:

```py
def limit_32bit_rational(f: float) -> Fraction:
    tmp = Fraction(f).limit_denominator(0xFFFF_FFFF)
    if tmp.numerator <= 0xFFFF_FFFF:
        # makes sure we don't flip if numerator is 0
        return tmp
    else:
        # flip numerator with denominator to limit the inputs numerator
        tmp = Fraction(numerator=tmp.denominator, denominator=tmp.numerator).limit_denominator(0xFFFF_FFFF)
        return Fraction(numerator=tmp.denominator, denominator=tmp.numerator)
```